# access parent method from child object with attributes in php?

Tags: php, class

I have the following `PHP` classes:

```
class a {
    public function vw($xc) {
        return $xc;
    }
}

class b extends a {
    public function wv() {
        echo vw() . 'from b via wv';
    }
}

$d = new a;
echo $d->vw('this is a');
$c = new b;
echo $c->vw('this is a from b via a');
$c->wv();
```

The output I am getting is:

```
   this is a
```

Why am I not getting the outputs of `echo $c->vw('this is a from b via a');` and `c->wv();` ?

Comment: Can you please format the code and correct the errors (no `test` or `t` class in there)?

Comment: sorry about that @jan

Comment: *"Why am I not getting the outputs of echo $c->vw('this is a from b via a'); and c->wv(); ?"* -- because the script triggers a fatal error on the line `echo vw() . 'from b via wv';`. There is no function `vw()` and that makes your script crash. Enable [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). Don't cross the road with closed eyes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a parent's method via `parent::`, e.g. `parent::vw()`. But the method `vw` of class `a` expects a parameter, so this code snippet won't work at all. But you should get the idea of using the parent keyword.

```
class a {
    public function vw($xc) {
        return $xc;
    }
}

class b extends a {
    public function wv() {
        echo parent::vw() . 'from b via wv';
    }
}

$d = new a;
echo $d->vw('this is a');
$c = new b;
echo $c->vw('this is a from b via a');
$c->wv();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php

https://3v4l.org/0MkQI

Answer (score 0):

In the class "b", you should write the function vw as:

```
   public  function wv(){
     echo $this->vw() . "from b via wv\n";
   }
```

Besides, in your last line the call of $c->wv() lacks a parameter:
$c->wv("I'm a missing parameter");

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        class a { 
            public tt;

               public function vw($xc){
                   $this->tt = $xc;
            return $this->tt;
        }
}

class b extends a
{
   public function(){
   return $this->tt. 'from b via wv'
}
}
```